# Why i get this error with opencv and houghlines?

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I'm using VS2010, OpenCV 2.1, Windows XP and I get the error:Exception at memory location

**Generally this is because something in NULL, but this is not the case:**

```
VideoCapture cap =  VideoCapture(); // open the default camera
cap.open("smartbeam1.avi");
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

Mat edges,color_dst;
Mat frame ;

namedWindow("original",1);
namedWindow("edges",1);

for(;;)
{
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);

//Houg
    vector<Vec2f> lines;
    **HoughLines(edges, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100 );//I Get Location Memory**
...
}
```

Comment: your code works fine on Ubuntu 12.10, Opencv 2.4.3.

Comment: Im using windows xp :( .

Comment: Please try newer OpenCV version.

Answer (score 0):

**best used**

vector lines;
HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, threshold,minLineLengh,maxLineGap );